# Disable default cell selection in datagridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have DataGridView to load some data programmatically. After inserting my data I am showing the DataGridView . Here by default the 1st row 0th column cell is selected. But I don't need that. I have tried to disable that option.

```
datagridviewname.currentcell=null
```

But it will not work. Any body can help me to solve my problem.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why u set it null? It should be like following. I think it will work

```
dataGridViewName.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false;
```

if it is **1st row 0th**, then

```
dataGridViewName.Rows[1].Cells[0].Selected = false;
```

Answer (score 16):

Set `CurrentCell` `Selected` property to `False` like:

```
   dataGridViewName.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
```

Comment: Asker didn't ask for CurrentCell. He asked for 1st row 0th

Comment: When the DataGridView loads it points to Row 1 and 0th (or 1st) column thus the current cell and that's basically what the OP tried to point out I guess.

Comment: This will work for any default cell selected unless you have code that selects Row 1 over Row 0.

Comment: i think the answer makes more sense when that line is put in form load or something like that ?

Answer (score 15):

On the DataGridView create an event for `DataBindingComplete` then add this method `datagridview1.ClearSelection()`

```
private void datagridview1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    datagridview1.ClearSelection();
}
```

Comment: perfect solution.

Comment: ((DataGridView)sender).ClearSelection();

Answer (score 4):

The only way is this:

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dataGridView.ClearSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should perform clear selection inside form load event of the form instead of constructor.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // You will get selectedCells count 1 here
 DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection selectedCells = dataGridView.SelectedCells;
 // Call clearSelection 
 dataGridView.ClearSelection();
 // Now You will get selectedCells count 0 here
 selectedCells = dataGridViewSchedule.SelectedCells;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx)

> You can set this property to null to temporarily remove the focus rectangle, but when the control receives focus and the value of this property is null, it is automatically set to the value of the FirstDisplayedCell property.

So looks like setting it to null only works if it wasn't the first row first column cell.