# Click on first datagrid row don't trigger selectedIndex change

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TabItem Header="Presentation">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CombinedPresentation , Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ObjectName" Binding="{Binding ObjectName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="bActivated" Binding="{Binding bActivated}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Presentation Piece" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=PieceEnabled}">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CombinedPresentationPiece , Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

SelectedIndex bind:

```
public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == -1)
            {
                PieceEnabled = false;
                _selectedIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                PieceEnabled = true;
                _selectedIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                DoSomeLogic();
            }

        }
    }
    private int _selectedIndex = 0;
```

and enabling second tab:

```
private bool _pieceEnabled= false;
    public bool PieceEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _pieceEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            _pieceEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

DataSource for datagrid

```
private List<CombinedPresentationDto> _combinedPresentation;
    public List<CombinedPresentationDto> CombinedPresentation
    {
        get
        {
            return _combinedPresentation;
        }
        set
        {
            _combinedPresentation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

filing datasource:

```
private void GetPresentation()
    {
        try
        {
            string query = @"Select * from testTable";
            Presentation = dataContext.ExecuteQuery<PresentationDto>(query, new string[] { }).ToList();
            if (Presentation.Count > 0 && GetPresentationPieces())
            {
                CombinedPresentation = PresentationCombiner.CombinePresentations(Presentation, PresentationPiece);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

PresentationCombiner i just findind pairs between Presentation and PresentationPiece and merging them into one object.

My problem is e.g. Datagrid display two rows. If user select one of the rows then second tab should be enabled ( it is displaying data connected to row selected). But selecting first row do not trigger `selectedindex`. User need to select second row then first one to trigger selecting first one

Answer (score -1):

Without being able to see your code for populating the DataGridView, I would guess that you already have the first row selected, so clicking on it doesn't change the SelectedIndex.   Make sure that you have don't have a row selected after populating your DataGridView.

[Disable current cell selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209234/disable-default-cell-selection-in-datagridview)

Comment: I updated my question. Data is just from sql query then i just transform it from list of one type object into list of another type objects

Comment: After populating, your DatGridView, check it's SelectedIndex property.  For SelectedIndexChanged to be called when clicking the first row,it should be greater than 0,